# Can you say walk/be down the street if the street actually is steep and goes up?

Tags: idioms

Can you say “walk/be down the street” if the street actually is steep and goes up? Can you say “walk up the street”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly say "walk up the street".

The notion of which way is "up" and which is "down" is a combination of literal and metaphorical.

"Up" might be literal (going in the direction of increasing height) or it might indicate "coming" or "approaching me". It might relate to "downtown" or "high street"

You can also say "along the street".

Comment: Ohhhhh! So “up” can mean approaching! That clarifies a LOT! Thanks!

Comment: "Up" can also mean "going north", especially in cities with a rectangular grid of streets.